# Can someone help me identify the cause and resolve distorted sound on 18.10?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, 18.10

Actually since 18.04 (now updated to 18.10) my Gigabyte GA-AX370 Gaming K7 with "Line Out-Family 17h (models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller produces a distortion noise in the sound for no reason and all sources.
Changing the settings to 5.0 or 5.1 or 2.1 makes it better but only temporary.
I have a simple setup with 2 JBL speakers, nothing fancy.
Over-Amplification is not on (not that it makes any difference).
Appreciate the help.